# Errors after creating new Azure Function app in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

After creating a new Azure Function app running on .NET6 project in Visual Studio 2022, I'm getting errors (I I didn't change anything in the newly created project):

> The type or namespace name '`actionresult`' could not be found

My `.csproj` file:

[image: csproj-file]

I tried repairing visual studio 2022. I have the same issue if I create a function app in .NET5, .NET3. If someone also had this issue it would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Error messages are text and so are StackOverflow questions. You can edit your question and include the error details so that others are not inconvenienced while trying to help you.

Comment: Ok, i changed this

Comment: my guess is that 'actionresult' should  be `ActionResult`

Comment: Sorry, I'm just tried to find this 6 hours and added this error maybe to roughly. 
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'IActionResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) FunctionApp.

Answer (score -1):

Ok I'm found the solution.
Deleting all folders and files from:

> C:\Users\User_name\.nuget\packages

solved the issue.

Comment: No this did not fix it. The packages are re-downloaded and still missing the reference.