# Azure Function App deployed to Azure: "Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0"

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I recently built an Azure Function App in .NET 6, v4. It worked perfectly fine locally then I attempted to publish to Azure where I got the following error:

```
 "Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0".
```

I originally had a much newer version, but after googling I found a post with seemingly the same issue where the user was recommended to downgrade to `3.1.0`. I did that (all nugets), but it did not work.

I have confirmed that the Function App is running v4, and that the Azure portal is configured for v4.

These are my used nugets:

I tried downgrading Nugets to 3.1.0, I expected this to work as I've seen numerous Forum posts where this did work. It did not though.

Answer (score 0):

I tried deploying Azure Function with .net 6.0 V4 Isolated and it got deployed successfully like below:-

My **`.net 6.0 v4 function`** **`.csproj`** file:-

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.18.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.13.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**`Function.cs:-`**

```c
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp2
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

            response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Make sure you set the Target Framework and
Target Runtime to 6.0 like below:-

[image]

[image]

***Click on Publish and the function will be deployed in the Function app like below:-***

[image]

[image]

***Make sure you have the same settings in your Function app:-***

[image]

Also, If the issue persists, According to this [SO thread answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71834908/errors-after-creating-new-azure-function-app-in-net-6) by Racki Kamil. Try to delete this file from your local machine:-

```
C:\Users\username\.nuget\packages
```

Delete the packages folder and re-build your function app:-

[image]

I'd  also advise double-checking your project files to make sure you've correctly updated them for Azure Functions refer - [**4.0**](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/migrate-version-1-version-4.md). You might also want to see whether there are any other dependencies that call for a particular **`Microsoft version.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.`**

If the problems persist, you might want to try creating a fresh Azure Function App project in .NET 6 Isolated like above and transferring your code there. This can assist guarantee that all required dependencies are present and that your project is configured properly.

**Refer this Blog for more details:-**

[Build Azure Functions V4 with .NET 6 (kontext.tech)](https://kontext.tech/article/794/build-azure-functions-with-net-6)

Comment: I'm currently building to a pre-created Azure Function App. Which apparently is set to Linux OS. Does this matter and should I instead get the admins to re-create it with the parameters you provided?

I will try your tips though, thank you very much.

I would also like to inform you that my project was built on .NET 6 v4 since the begining. But if worst comes to worst I might give the last two points a try just in case.

Comment: It should work fine in Function app Linux Os too